# Always download file again when open a file in NetBeans IDE 6.8

Tags: netbeans, download, netbeans6.8, file-transfer, fileupdate

I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.8.

When I open a file, NetBeans opens an old file from my computer, not the actual one from the web-server. The problem is when some one else has edited the file on the web-server I need to download the file before I open it, so I don't lose the new changes.

What I want to do is that NetBeans always download the file from the web-server when I open a file. Do you know how I can make NetBeans to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans doesn't really play well with remote files.
You have a few options:

1. dont use remote files :-p ... you could look into using Subversion for 2 people editing the same file problem.
2. use a ftp disk program that maps a certain FTP server as a local directory. You can google it to find out more about it.